# Common Lisp Packages - How to deal when a package might not be loaded?

Tags: package, common-lisp

Assume a common lisp library user could also have loaded package A, package B or neither. I want to be able to accept objects from either package. Ideally it would just be a case of defining a method on those objects. However, if the packages are not loaded at compile time, trying to do that will generate a Package XYZ does not exist error. I don't want to force users to load both packages, so any suggestions on how I can do conditional calls at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something similar to the following:

```
(defun foo (x)
   (cond
      ((find-package :bar) (funcall (find-symbol "x" :bar) x))
      ((find-package :baz) (funcall (find-symbol "y" :baz) x))))
```

Basically, use `find-package` and `find-symbol` to check if the package exists and get the symbol from the package if it does. Then, you can use `symbol-function` and `symbol-value` to get the function or value associated with the symbol. In my example, `funcall` automatically looks up the function associated with the symbol returned by `find-symbol`, so `symbol-function` wasn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you. The only change I had to make was the strings "x" and "y" in your example needed to be uppercased.